# nginx how to redirect to different routes in localhost

Tags: nginx

I have two basic questions about nginx:

**How to set `aliases` in localhost ?**

To be able to reach many differents projects on localhost (e.g localhost/project1, localhost/project2 ...).

I have tried

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location /project1 { //Is it to match localhost/project1?
        root /var/www/project1/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /project2 {
        root /var/www/project2/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

But i get a 404, i can't understand why...

**How to organize our domains ?**

I have seen many conf using the same organization than apache2 (`sites-available` and `sites-enabled`), but it doesn't seems to include these repositories by default, how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure you are referring to with `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` can also be replicated in nginx. In fact, this is how I have my server configs stored as well.

They are not read in a standard installation of nginx (from source). You'll have to edit `httpd.conf` and add the following line to the bottom of the `http` block:

```
include /path/to/sites-enabled/*;
```

---

As for aliases, it is difficult to determine what exactly you are looking for. Are you looking to be able to access `example.org/project1` via the url `project1.example.org`?

If so, one of the ways to do this would be to set a `CNAME` record for `project1` to point to the IP address of your server. Once completed, you would modify that site's `server` block to accept connections from that virtual host:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name project1.example.org;
    ... other declarations...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the include works great (the file is `default.conf` by default on my env). About the alias, i just want to use localhost/project1 to go to the project one and localhost/project2 for project 2, i get an error on the `/`, actually i have `server_name localhost` wich catch all the url `localhost/*` so i can only access one project

Comment: Good morning @Ludo - where are project1 and project2 located? They must be within the document root as defined in the `root` statement. Otherwise they are inaccessible via nginx (unless via a http redirect, as opposed to a rewrite)